# Hidden NFT smart contract address from public use

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, nft

I am new in blockchain and NFT world.

if a collection hides its smart contract, where its functions become not open to public use, how is it possible for some marketplaces can call smart contract's functions like the safeTransfer function, or get the total supply function ?..

Answer (score 1):

All smart contracts bytecode on public networks (such as Ethereum and BSC) is public by definition.

Their addresses might not be published by their authors, but there are few ways how marketplaces and other offchain apps might find these collections:

1. The marketplace is listening to specific events emitted on the network. Since the network is public, all emitted events are public as well. The NFT standards ([ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155)) define a set of specific events (`Transfer` on 721; `TransferSingle` and `TransferBatch` on 1155) that each collection contract is supposed to emit when an NFT token is minted, transferred or burned.
2. Each transaction on the network is public as well. So again, the marketplace can subscribe to receipts of all new transactions ([docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactionreceipt)) that created a contract (property `contractAddress` of the receipt is not null), and then perform some further checks to validate if the contract is an NFT collection. For example by trying to call its `supportsInterface()` method again defined in the standards.